# Type checking issues with Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am having two specific issues with Typescript and the Redux reducer.

**MyReducer**

```
const defaultState = {
    selectedLocation: { id: 0, name: 'No Location' },
    allLocations: [{ id: 0, name: 'No Location' }],
    selectedUser: null,
};

export default function LocationsReducer(
    state = defaultState,
    action: LocationActionTypes,
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_ALL_LOCATIONS:
            return {
                ...state,
                locations: [...defaultState.allLocations, ...action.locations],
            };
        case SET_SELECTED_LOCATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedLocation: action.location,
            };
        case SET_SELECTED_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedUser: action.user,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Types file**

```
export interface loadAllLocations {
    type: string;
    locations: Location[];
}

export interface setSelectedLocation {
    type: string;
    location: Location;
}

export interface setUser {
    type: string;
    user: User; // imported from another types file
}

export type LocationActionTypes =
    | loadAllLocations
    | setSelectedLocation 
    | setUser ;

export type Location = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
};
```

I get two different errors:

1. Because each of my action types has a differently named property (e.g. `location`, `locations`, `user`), Typescript gives me an error:

```
    Property 'locations' does not exist on type 'LocationActionTypes'.
    Property 'locations' does not exist on type 'setSelectedLocation'
```

However, according to the Redux docs, it should be possible to name the properties something different: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-reducers

2. Let's say I give in and name all my properties `data` instead of `location`, `locations`, and `user`. That gets rid of the previous error. But now, I get another error:

In the `LOAD_ALL_LOCATIONS` switch case, I get a red squiggly line on a `...action.data` saying:

```
Type 'Location | Location[] | User' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

The reason this is happening is because other action types has just a single object but in the case of `LOAD_ALL_LOCATIONS`, my data is an array and use the spread operator on it.

How do I get past these two errors?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you missed is this https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-actions--action-creators

Especially this part:

```
interface SendMessageAction {
  type: typeof SEND_MESSAGE // here it is not typed "string"
  payload: Message
}
```

If you specify the value that `type` should have for each action, typescript will be able to infer action type in the switch statements of the reducer.

Answer (score 1):

The type should be more specific in your action types, not just a string:

```js
export interface loadAllLocations {
    type: typeof LOAD_ALL_LOCATIONS;
    locations: Location[];
}

export interface setSelectedLocation {
    type: typeof SET_SELECTED_LOCATION;
    location: Location;
}

export interface setUser {
    type: typeof SET_SELECTED_USER;
    user: User; // imported from another types file
}
```